# Xcode4, iOS: Copied a target, why can't I change the identifier?

Tags: ios4, xcode4

This is diving me crazy - I've copied a target for my iOS project in Xcode4 - however, the Target Identifier field under "iOS Application Target" on the Summary page for my target is uneditable.

How do I change the target's identifier?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It gets the identifier from the product name. Go into build settings, then scroll down to the *Packaging* section. Change the product name and the identifier will change accordingly.