# How to maintain both debug and appstore release version in test device?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an iPhone application released at App Store. In development of next version, I want to maintain these two versions on test device(iPhone).

But when I tried to run the next version for debug on the test device, it overwrites the release version downloaded from the App Store. At the first, I guessed it can be done by changing the version number in xcode target setting > summary > iOS Application Target, but it's not. I have changed the both 'Version' and 'Build' number in iOS Application Target.

App Store version number is 1.1 and debug version number is 1.2
So, how can I get this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please `duplicate` the target and change its `bundle identifier` .
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5725711/667586

Answer (score 1):

Instead of maintaining multiple targets, you can use build settings to change the bundle identifier based on the build configuration as explained [here](http://swwritings.com/post/2013-05-20-concurrent-debug-beta-app-store-builds).

To summarize, change the bundle identifier in your target's info to something like `com.mycompany.my-app${BUNDLE_ID_SUFFIX}`. Then create a new user-defined build setting called `BUNDLE_ID_SUFFIX` and set its Release value to an empty string and its Debug value to something like `.debug`.

It can also be helpful to do this with the bundle display name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same bundle identifier, you cannot keep two apps in the device/simulator with the same bundle identifier.

The alternative is,You can have two configs.

Select project in Navigator -> Select your project under PROJECT -> Select info tab -> and in Configuration, click on the plus button,  to create a new configuration say, 'AppStore', copy the release config.

Now, select your target, select build settings, you can find the AppStore configuration in many settings.

You can create a separate info.plist for you app store config. Make a copy of the current info.plist and the create another one for appstore config. say, Info-AppStore.plist.

Now, select your target, select build settings, search for info plist. There for the AppStore config, give the name of your Info-AppStore.plist file. 
In you app store plist file, you can give a separate bundle identifier for you app store and debug app. And they can coexists together with the same code base.

Answer (score -1):

sorry it is not possible two apps with a same bundle identifier (or) for temporary you can change second version apps bundle then only you have two apps at the same time