# Having both debug and release builds on the iphone

Tags: ios, xcode

we are building an app right now, but we would like to use it as users ourselves (dogfooding).

What is the simplest way to get a production version on our phones that will not be overwritten when we run the build on it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to maintain both debug and appstore release version in test device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711106/how-to-maintain-both-debug-and-appstore-release-version-in-test-device)

Comment: not really, the answer provided here is directly answering the question and is a much more specific and useful to my situation. thanks @paul-s!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your build settings you can add a suffix to the bundle identifier

[image]